# How to implement Poisson regression with scikit-learn for count data prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics, poisson

I'm looking for a way to couple [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) with [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). After a simple Linear Regression, its result is a numerical value that i would like to use in a Poisson Distribution, because i need the *probability* and i need the *probability discrete for the number of events that occur successively and independently in a given time interval*.

**MY CASE IS:** Having an independent variable `Team_A__goal_scored = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]` and a dependent variable `Team_B__goal_conceded = [2, 1, 3, 0, 1]`, i would like to calculate the probability that Team A can score `2 goals` exact to Team B (so relate Team A's attack and Team B's defense). Running the regression and setting 2 goals as output with `test = myfunc(2)`, i get `1.28`:

```
import numpy
from scipy import stats

Team_B__goal_conceded = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1] #Var indipendent (x)
Team_A__goal_scored = [2, 1, 3, 0, 1] ##Var dipendent (y)

slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(Team_B__goal_conceded, Team_A__goal_scored)

def myfunc(Team_B__goal_conceded):
   return slope * Team_B__goal_conceded + intercept

regression_scored_2 = myfunc(2) #result: 1.28
```

**PROBLEM:** The specific problem is that i need a probability, instead by performing a simple Linear Regression i obtain for example `1.28` which is not a probability.

To recap, I know the initial starting point with `Team_B__goal_conceded` and `Team_A__goal_scored`, i know what i want to achieve (probability of Team A scoring exactly `2` goals to Team B), but i don't know how i can achieve it. Having reflected that Linear Regression is not for me because i don't get a percentage, I thought that "maybe" a solution could be the [Poisson Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) (also called **Log-Linear Regression**) could be useful to me, but I'm having trouble using it. I'm not sure if it is the solution to what I'm looking for, so I'm looking for someone who knows how to use it and tell me if it is useful for what I would like to achieve and who tells me how to use it. If this is not the case, then surely there are other ways to use the result of Linear Regression in a Poisson distribution.

**EXPECTATIONS:** The final output i want to get are the individual probabilities of a soccer team scoring 0 goals, 1 goal, 2 goals, 3 goals, etc, after running the regression. To be precise, i only need exactly `2` goals, so I would like this final output:

```
The probability that Team A scores exactly 2 goals against Team B is: x %
```

**MY CODE:**
I tried to use [sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html), but it doesn't work properly. As I said above, I don't even know if this is the most suitable solution for my case or if there are better and more appropriate methods. If this is not the case, then surely there are other ways to use the result of Linear Regression in a Poisson distribution.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.PoissonRegressor()
Team_A__goal_scored = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1] #Var indipendent (x)
Team_B__goal_conceded = [2, 1, 3, 0, 1] #Var dipendent (y)

a=clf.fit(Team_A__goal_scored, Team_B__goal_conceded)
print("Fit a Generalized Linear Model: ", a, "\n")

b = clf.score(Team_A__goal_scored, Team_B__goal_conceded)
print("Compute D^2, the percentage of deviance explained: ", b, "\n")

c = clf.coef_
print("Estimated coefficients for the linear predictor: ", c, "\n")

d= clf.intercept_
print("Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added to linear predictor: ", d, "\n")

e=clf.predict([[1, 1], [3, 4]])
print("Predict using GLM with feature matrix X: ", e, "\n")
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1. 2. 2. 3. 1.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

because should the lists be like (as the [scikit-learn link](https://rg/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html) shows)  for example: `X = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 3]] and y = [12, 17, 22, 21]`, but i didn't understand how i could use mine in this way.

I also don't know how to set that the result must be exactly `2` goals (probability of Team A scoring exactly 2 goals to Team B)

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I fix the question, wrote down the specific problem and added more clarity

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a generalized linear model using Poisson distribution: https://towardsdatascience.com/poisson-regression-and-generalised-linear-models-606fe5f7c1fd

Comment: @Duffymo Maybe yes, exactly. I can't see the page, because the author has made this story available only to Medium members. If you understand what I'm looking for, could you show me an answer with a code example please?

Comment: Sorry, no code sample.  I think this should be enough of a hint to let you dig into it yourself.

Comment: @duffymo Actually I also wrote it in the question I needed about generalized linear model using Poisson distribution. I also included the Wikipedia link in the question. The question is long, maybe you missed it. Anyway, thanks anyway, I really appreciate your kindness :)

Comment: SciKit Learn has a PoissonRegressor.  Maybe you can try that: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach with `PoissonRegressor` is suitable for your problem, but it expects a 2D array for the features (`X`). You can reshape your 1D array using `numpy.reshape`:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor

Team_A__goal_scored = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)
Team_B__goal_conceded = np.array([2, 1, 3, 0, 1])
```

Then you can fit the model:

```py
clf = PoissonRegressor()
clf.fit(Team_A__goal_scored, Team_B__goal_conceded)
```

Then you can make the prediction (e.g. `Team_A__goal_scored = 2`):

```py
lambda_pred = clf.predict(np.array([[2]]))[0]
```

Then you can use the Poisson probability mass function to find the probability of scoring exactly 2 goals:

```py
from scipy.stats import poisson

probability_two_goals = poisson.pmf(2, lambda_pred)
```

This gives you the probability that Team A scores exactly 2 goals against Team B.

Comment: Wow, great!!! A thousand thanks :) A little clarification: where did you write clf.predict(np.array([[2]]))[0], why did you use [0]? What is it for? Anyway, out of curiosity: is Poisson Regression the best method to get what i want? Or are there other different methods too? Would Bayesian inference have helped me get a percentage? (I'm not very expert in Regressions or general statistics)

Comment: (continuation of comment above) For predictive purposes, besides to clf.fit, as a secondary parameter what is the most important one that I could consider between clf.score (result 0.097), clf.coef_ (result -0.18) and clf.intercept_ (result 0.65) ?

Comment: @Tappetinoorange Glad I could help. In this case, kindly consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1133249). `[0]` is to access the first (and only) element. Poisson Regression is one way to address the problem, there might be others like _Negative Binomial Regression_, each has pros and cons. Note that coefficients and intercepts are more about understanding the model rather than evaluating its performance.

Comment: Of course i accept your answer :) Yesterday i voted for it, now i accept it. I hope you vote back. Thank you